# Error "Refused to connect to" when calling Rest API from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, callout

I want to make a REST API call from my LWC but when I make the callout I get this error

> Refused to connect to 'XXXXXXX' because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
> https://static.lightning.force.com https://api.bluetail.salesforce.com
> https://staging.bluetail.salesforce.com
> https://preprod.bluetail.salesforce.com XXXXXXX blob:
> *.visualforce.com XXXXX https://cs101.salesforce.com https://notification-service.sfproxy.null.fra.aws.sfdc.cl
> wss://notification-service.sfproxy.null.fra.aws.sfdc.cl"

I added the endpoint as CSP Trusted site and set the Remote Site Settiing for that enpoint but the error appears.

The Javascript code i very simple in that point (for now) and it is:

```
    fetch(calloutURI, {
        method: "GET"
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then(repos => {
         console.log(repos)
    });
```

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: is the connect-src checkbox checked on your CSP trusted site? Read this blog for more context https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/03/working-with-cors-and-csp-to-call-apis-from-lwc